# Aosp does not have tools/vendor/google3 project

Tags: android-studio, bazel

When I [build Android Studio](http://tools.android.com/build/studio) from source code using: '[bazel build //tools/adt/idea/...](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/bazel/README.md)' command can't always find 'tools/vendor/google3' module, isn't google no open source project?

```
zhangyang@zhangyang-OptiPlex-7040:~/aosp/gradle_3.1.2$ bazel build //tools/adt/idea/...
WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
..............................
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'binds.bzl': no such package '@blaze//': /home/zhangyang/.cache/bazel/_bazel_zhangyang/e54d4cb13781c1d72b64dc99700261fe/external/blaze must be an existing directory
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'binds.bzl': no such package '@blaze//': /home/zhangyang/.cache/bazel/_bazel_zhangyang/e54d4cb13781c1d72b64dc99700261fe/external/blaze must be an existing directory
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.621s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

the bazel WORKSPACE:
    load("//tools/base/bazel:repositories.bzl", "setup_external_repositories")
    setup_external_repositories()

```
local_repository(
     name = "blaze",
     path = "tools/vendor/google3/blaze",
)
load("@blaze//:binds.bzl", "blaze_binds")
blaze_binds()

http_archive(
 name = "bazel_toolchains",
 urls = [
  "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-toolchains/archive/b49ba3689f46ac50e9277dafd8ff32b26951f82e.tar.gz",
 "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-toolchains/archive/b49ba3689f46ac50e9277dafd8ff32b26951f82e.tar.gz",
 ],
 strip_prefix = "bazel-toolchains-b49ba3689f46ac50e9277dafd8ff32b26951f82e",
 sha256 = "1266f1e27b4363c83222f1a776397c7a069fbfd6aacc9559afa61cdd73e1b429",
)
```

But Aosp does not have tools/vendor/google3 project

Comment: This sounds like a bug, would you mind filing an issue on android studio?

Comment: i`m not sure it`s a bug，I think it can be solved in tackoverflow，Wait first

Comment: I'm facing the very same issue as you and I'm wondering if you have found a solution after all or not. Would love to hear your findings. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

- bazel build is broken in AOSP
- Use `<studio-master-dev>/tools/idea/build_studio.sh` instead
- Or if you just want build a submodule inside `tools/base` , simply run `gradle build`. You might have to remove some dead dependencies from `gradle.build` but this shouldn't be difficult to fix.

**Long version:**

I had encountered the same error message, and took a look in the `external`directory:

```
ls -lah ~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_xxx/89112fe8516b5fa5b01df0651312df31/external/
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x 2 xxx xxx 4.0K Dec 12 14:04 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 xxx xxx 4.0K Dec 12 14:04 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxx xxx   33 Dec 12 14:04 @bazel_tools.marker
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxx xxx  110 Dec 12 14:04 bazel_tools -> /home/xxx/.cache/bazel/_bazel_xxx/install/35f799b1c96ee2522d30a28ff4ef485a/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxx xxx   55 Dec 12 14:04 blaze -> /home/xxx/studio-master-dev/tools/vendor/google3/blaze
```

What is actually missing is `/tools/vendor/google3/blaze`. A quick Google search shows that blaze is an internal version of bazel, exclusively used within Google.

[A thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/126764883) in Android Studio's issue tracker also confirms that bazel build is broken in AOSP, with some bonus hints that build instructions in the `studio-master-dev` branch are all outdated (ouch). The issue is still open at the point of writing so if you are building Android Studio (or related tools), you might want to take a look at the latest discussion there.

Comment: `<studio-master-dev>/tools/idea/build_studio.sh` gives me the same errors about a missing  `@blaze//` package in `tools/vendor/google3/blaze`.  Any ideas on how to build Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Remove all references to tools/vendor/google from tools/base/bazel/toplevel.WORKSPACE:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/idea/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/RELEASE.md